# Get xml value with xslt for-each nested in multiple identical tags (python)

Tags: python, xml, xslt

```
<keywords>
  <theme>
    <themekt>THEME_KEY</themekt>
    <key>ONE</key>
    <key>TWO</key>
    <key>THREE</key>
    <key>FOUR</key>
    <key>FIVE</key>
  </theme>
  <theme>
    <themekt>KEY_TWO</themekt>
    <key>NONE</key>
    <key>SOME</key>
    <key>VALUE</key>
  </theme>
</keywords>
```

I need to get the values 1-5 from the 'key' tags nested under the first "theme" tag. Is there a way to retrieve these values without transforming the xml using xslt? I can't think of a way, so this is what I have tried using:

```
<xsl:for-each select="keywords/theme">
    <xsl:for-each select="key">
         <p><xsl:value-of select="key"/></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The above returns empty p tags in the html transformation. If I use the code below it will return only the first key tag value (ONE and NONE) in each "theme" tag.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="keywords/theme">
         <p><xsl:value-of select="key"/></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: To fix the first change the select: `<xsl:value-of-select="."/>`. But it will print out values for `key` children of both `theme` tags. You can fix that by using `select=keywords/theme[1]` in the outside `for-each`.  The second only executes on the first child of each `theme`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse this xml is one way of doing it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<keywords>
  <theme>
    <themekt>THEME_KEY</themekt>
    <key>ONE</key>
    <key>TWO</key>
    <key>THREE</key>
    <key>FOUR</key>
    <key>FIVE</key>
  </theme>
  <theme>
    <themekt>KEY_TWO</themekt>
    <key>NONE</key>
    <key>SOME</key>
    <key>VALUE</key>
  </theme>
</keywords>
'''

output = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
theme = soup.find('theme')
for key in theme.find_all('key'):
    output.append(str(key.text))

print output
```

This will give you:

```
['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE']
```

The `find` method returns you the first occurrence of the search criteria. In this case the search criteria is element with the tag name `theme`. If you wanted elements of the second `theme` tag, you would do `soup.find_all('theme')` which returns a list of `theme` tags and then select the second one as `soup.find_all('theme')[1]`

Hope this helps.